# Can I install Ubuntu to my 32 GB USB pen drive?

Tags: usb-drive, persistence, unetbootin

I want to install Ubuntu like how you would to a hard drive so I can use it as a portable system. I do not want a Live install; I want something where i can install updates, install drivers, and things like that. I'm really confused because I made a persistent install using UNetBootIn in Windows thinking that would allow me to do that and yet when I booted I still saw the "Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" icon.

Comment: Refer this http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key