# Will Ubuntu work,  if installed on Flash Drive?

Tags: installation, live-usb

Will I be able to use Ubuntu as an independent os, If I run it from a flash drive?
 In Other words, will everything work like as if the OS was installed on the actual HD of the system?

Access graphics driver, networking, file share, play games, run vms etc?

Edit: One more thing, lets say I boot the flash trough a vm and later through the pc it self, will this effect ubuntu on the flash badly? or is this not recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure it to install on the disk and run anything/everything from flash. Just make sure you don't install `grub` on the entire system.

Comment: I will be using a vm to install to the usb.

Comment: One more thing, lets say I boot the flash trough a vm and later through the pc it self, will this effect ubuntu on the flash badly? or is this not recommended?

Comment: @Marchosius add those information on the question by editing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do a full proper install of Ubuntu to a USB drive.
Everything will work just like the OS was installed on the actual HD.

Have a look at this question for instructions on installing Ubuntu to USB drives

[Can I install Ubuntu to my 32 GB USB pen drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive/170456#170456)

Comment: Link is very helpful thanx