# Save Changes When Running From USB.

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu

Basically, what i need to know is how do i save any changes i make when running Lubuntu from a USB drive?

My computer has no hard drive and so i have been booting Lubuntu in 'Try Lubuntu before installing' mode as a workaround. Unfortunately when i reboot my computer, any changes i've made are wiped; and this includes absolutely everything such as downloads, packages, Chromium extensions and system settings.

I'm sure this is because the hard drive is missing, but isn't it possible to save the data to another USB drive instead?

How do i overcome this issue and get my computer working properly again?

Thanks!

Comment: When creating the live USB there is an option called  Persistance allowing you to save files on the USB. If you have an external hard drive or 8GB + USB stick you could do a full / proper install of Ubuntu to that using the following instructions - http://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive/170456#170456

Comment: Thanks Fernhill Linux Project, that's probably the answer i was looking for, the Persistence option was something i didn't check when using the USB installer. Unfortunately i cannot test at the moment but i will have a go tonight and see what i can do. Best wishes, UbuntuRob.