# Installing Ubuntu on a HDD

Tags: installation, boot, external-hdd

I recently purchased a 2TB WD MyBook external hard-drive with the intention of installing Ubuntu on it in a way that will allow me to simply plug it in to any computer and boot MY Ubuntu from virtually anywhere. I now realize I should probably have consulted folk here before buying the HDD, but it's too late for that now.

I installed Ubuntu as I usually do, but it didn't work. After some investigation and much tweaking I managed to boot it -- once -- on my brother's laptop. Now I can't do that, and I still can't boot it from any other computer.

I'm perfectly willing to format it and start again. What is the best way to do this, preferably without using a LiveCD (as my own laptop doesn't have a CDROM)?

Comment: Look at answers to these questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive and http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator. In case there are issues you face please [edit] your question to add as much detail as possible (*"didn't work"* is not enough to give advice).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use UNetbootin to make the Harddrive a Live USB Stick (kinda).