# Ubuntu Install on external drive without touching the internal one

Tags: grub2

I thought that would be common question, but I could not find an answer so far.

How do I avoid GRUB2 to be installed at all? Whatever I try it always gets installed an than I can't boot Windows from internal disk when the external disk (with ubuntu) is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

When installing Ubuntu to the external drive, using the **something else** option, you need to ensure that you select the correct device for bootloader / grub installation.

Usually **Sda** is your internal drive and your USB drive will be **Sdb** if you have no other USB devices connected.

This way the internal hard drive / windows bootloader will not be modified in anyway.

Have a look at my answer on [How to Install Ubuntu To USB Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive/170456#170456), it has all the details and should help you.

Below is an image, showing the 'bootloader installation' menu highlighted in red at the bottom.

[image: bootloader install option]

Image Source : [help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing).

Comment: I've done this and it still writes an entry to the UEFI table on the HDD that is placed above Windows and requires the flash drive to be plugged in.