# Removing "install Lubuntu" icon from persistant USB

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb, icons

Thanks in advance for any help.

I want to give young students USB drives with persistent Lubuntu installs. When I prepare these drives, I move the desktop icon, "install Lubuntu" to the trash. I don't want the young students to be installing Lubuntu on the hard drives of their parents' computers. My problem is that when I reboot the USB, the "install Lubuntu" icon has returned to the desktop, even though all the other changes I made persist after rebooting.

How can I permanently, persistently remove the install Lubuntu icon from the desktop?

Comment: What you *probably* want to do is called a "Live CD Customization" and help.ubuntu.com has a great article on that!

  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "Install Lubuntu" icon, you could remove the installer, Ubiquity. To do so, you'll have to [customize the ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization). When you arrive at the step where you `chroot` into the extracted ISO, you can uninstall the installer with

```
apt-get purge ubiquity
```

The resulting ISO will then have no installer. This should also remove the installation icon from the desktop. If it doesn't remove the installation .desktop file in `/home/lubuntu/`

---

To remove the Installation options from GRUB, open the file `USBROOT/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in a text editor. This file contains all boot menu entries in the following format:

```
menuentry "Name" {
    # some config
}
```

Remove the entries you don't need, then save. If you use UNetBootin for creation of the boot sticks, also edit the file `USBROOT/syslinux.cfg`. Here the format of the entries is diffrent:

```
label ubnentryX
#config
```

Remove the entries you don't need, and decrement the following entry numbers (X) so they are in a sequence starting at 0. Again, save and exit.

Comment: No success. I only have a file called "loopback.cfg" in the /boot/grub location. It is concerned with editing the grub menu. I want to permanently remove an icon "install Lubuntu" from the desktop. The measures suggested here do not accomplish this. At some point I may get around to altering the grub menu but I wanted to remove the icon from the desktop first, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find an answer for the same question and found one I could adapt. In my case, I'm in Lubuntu, so I made a file with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh 
mv -f /home/lubuntu/Desktop/ubiquity.desktop /home/lubuntu/Desktop/.ubiquity.desktop
```

I've not tried to remove it, because being "hidden" is enough for me. But replacing with `rm -f /home/lubuntu/Desktop/ubiquity.desktop` instead, should also do the job.

I placed it in `~/.local/bin` and named it `unubiquous.sh` and then add it to the lxsession autostart list, reboot, and voilá, it's gone!

Comment: I ended up using the Porteus distro. I prefer the XFCE de, and it does all I need without any pesky icons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need an answer. But I will do it anyway.

If you install the Linux directly on USB, it will remove the Installer app. The main idea is in 2 steps:

1. Set your pendrive (usb) root `/` flag.
2. Install bootload on the pendrive that you set root flag.

Detail of how to installing Linux on USB in here: [Can I install Ubuntu to my 32 GB USB pen drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170454)