# Can i keep progress on a bootable usb

Tags: boot, software-installation

To be more specific, i have a 16 GB USB with Ubuntu on it, and i use it to boot from it, but i want to save all my installations etc. so when i restart the computer or reboot again i wont have to restart my installations again.
I also used terminal do install these programs, so will it be possible to sort of change the place where it is installed that way it will be on my C drive and ill only have to boot Ubuntu to run them.
so in short I want to use the USB as another hard drive for the laptop.
thanks,

Comment: You can just have the live installer, which boots and lets you install system. You can add persistence to live installer which lets you save some data. Or you can do a full install just like you would to any second drive whether internal, external hard drive or larger flash drive. I have a full install on a 16GB flash drive. But you have to use Something Else install option so you can have grub2's boot loader on the flash drive. Otherwise grub defaults to sda or usually internal drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation Better with Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  But atleast you need 20 GB. So you can work freely. And your question is a duplicate of this post. 
[Can I install Ubuntu to my 32 GB USB pen drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the usb startup disk creator to place the iso image on the USB stick, select the option to store documents and settings in reserved space, and allocate enough space to hold the extra things you wish to install.

Comment: so if understand correctly i should do partition one that hold the iso boot disc and the other is a free space and i change in the settings to save everything their

Comment: @OmarElshazly, not at all.  Startup disk creator creates a single partition that contains the required files, taken from the .iso, to boot.  It optionally adds another file to store any changes you make to the system while it is running.  You don't have to worry about any of this: just choose the option in the startup disk creator to store changes in xx gb of space.