# How can I make Ubuntu 100% installed and portable

Tags: portable

I want to make Ubuntu 14.0.4 full installed and portable to a USB, so I don't have to use windows at my school, I've tried heaps of methods and I don't know how, I am running windows 7 and the USB is 8gigs

Comment: Please be specific what exactly you want to do and why?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials about this type of thing online, and a number of different ways to do it.  If you ask a question like this, you'll have to be specific about what you've tried, and WHY it hasn't worked for you.  Otherwise we can't give anything that you can't find elsewhere.

Comment: I think you are asking for this? I am trying the top answer right now, and I am curious if it will work. http://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive

Comment: I have tried that answer I linked to in the previous comment, and it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

(please note this answer is a best guess, so take it with a grain of salt)
You would to boot from a different Ubuntu live USB, with the destination USB also plugged in, but empty. You would need to either create custom partitions using the installer, or, if it recognizes the USB as a destination for install, simply choose the USB. After installing to the USB you would need to do the normal steps of booting from a USB to use it.

Comment: I have tried this answer, and it works. However, it is formulated much more clearly and detailed in the top answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive