# Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: windows

Looking to use Ubuntu for some projects but wish to keep my Windows 10 OS.

Is there a way of using a flash drive/SSD drive as a disc so I do not have to switch without having to log out via the removal tool to get into Ununtu.

Any help on using this switching of formats would be helpful.

Comment: Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/q/397481/146105

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/installubuntutousbdrive.html) is a video tutorial on how to install Ubuntu to a USB. It was made by user [Fernhill Linux Project](https://askubuntu.com/users/71699/fernhill-linux-project). You can find a question he answered about the matter [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive).

Alternatively you could setup a Ubuntu virtual machine. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzhA5p-EzqY) is a video tutorial on that.