# Portable USB does not boot

Tags: boot, usb, portable

I tried to make a portable usb ( [Can I install Ubuntu to my 32 GB USB pen drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive/324899#324899) )
and followed these steps but i think that something went wrong with selecting the location of the bootloader because even though I selected my 32GB Usb drive it installed the bootloader to my hard drive and I cannot boot the usb on another PC.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: At "installation type" select "Something else" press continue. Confirm Device is correct, pendrive should be selected for bootloader installation here.

Answer (score 3):

I reinstalled following these steps https://www.dionysopoulos.me/253-portable-ubuntu-on-usb-hdd.html and it worked ... but thanks anyway

> **What you need**
>
> - An empty external (USB) hard drive. I used a USB 3 drive enclosure with a cheap 256Gb SSD. For those of you worrying about performance,
>     the USB 3.0 port is faster than the maximum transfer rate of any SSD
>     I've seen to this date.
> - Ubuntu Linux bootable USB drive. Very easy to create using Rufus on Windows. I used a cheap, promotional flash drive. Reduce, reuse,
>     recycle FTW.
> - Windows System Repair Disc (a bootable USB drive with Windows recovery tools which you can make yourself) or a Windows installation
>     or rescue CD-ROM / DVD-ROM. I used another promotional flash drive.
>
> Remember to take backups of all your critical files and folders before
>   continuing. You are going to make changes to your computer. If it
>   breaks don't cry, I warned you. Also test both your bootable media.
>   Twice. You will need them both!
>
> **Caveats**
>
> Having a dual- or multi-boot system isn't as straightforward as it
>   used to be a decade ago. Nowadays, in the interest of security,
>   performance and backwards compatibility, there are many semi-hidden
>   options and features which can get in your way. Given enough
>   experience and patience you can work around them. Below is a selection
>   of problems that got me moderately stumped along the way.
>
> **Secure boot caveat**
>
> I have only tested these instructions with Secure Boot turned off.
>   Even though Ubuntu does support Secure Boot (it comes with signed
>   bootloaders) I have no idea if my method uses the signed bootloaders
>   or not. I suggest turning off Secure Boot if possible.
>
> **FastBoot caveats**
>
> Many boards come with some sort of "fast boot" or "boot optimization"
>   options. For example, my Intel NUC has an option called Fast Boot
>   which won't let me choose an alternative boot device at startup. It
>   also has an option to support Intel Rapid Start Technology which does
>   get in the way of booting to multiple OS. I had to disable both.
>
> It's worth noting that Windows 8 and 10 have an Fast Startup or Fast
>   Boot feature. This feature takes some shortcuts when it comes to
>   booting and also makes the NTFS filesystem remain in a dirty state,
>   making it unwriteable from Linux. It's best to understand what it does
>   and disable it if you plan on writing to your Windows drive from
>   Linux.
>
> **USB host controller caveat**
>
> Some firmwares will present the USB host controller as UHCI (USB 1.1)
>   at boot time. When Linux probes for an xHCI (USB 3) host controller
>   during the boot process they will respond positively. At this time
>   Linux loads the xHCI driver and the USB host controller resets itself.
>
> However, your root filesystem is inside a device attached to this USB
>   controller. Therefore the controller resetting means that Linux can no
>   longer communicate with the USB-attached hard drive. Therefore the
>   Linux boot will hang forever without any further indication as to what
>   went wrong.
>
> Most affected boards (including my Intel NUC) have an option to enable
>   the xHCI host controller interface by default. Enabling the xHCI
>   option in the BIOS fixes the hanging boot issue. If you are only using
>   modern operating systems with USB 3 support (anything newer than and
>   including Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu Linux 15.04) you can safely enable
>   that option.
>
> **Installing Linux**
>
> Boot your computer from the Ubuntu Linux bootable USB drive. Remember
>   that you may have to enter your computer's boot manager to do that (on
>   my Intel NUC I have to press F10; on most other BIOS I've seen it's
>   F9; consult your BIOS documentation).
>
> Install Ubuntu Linux regularly. When it prompts you about the disk
>   layout choose Something Else and partition your external HDD the way
>   you want. I chose to create a modestly sized root partition (about
>   40Gb), a swap partition that's as big as the biggest RAM configuration
>   I am going to be using this installation with plus one Gb (my
>   computers max out at 16Gb so I made a 17Gb swap partition) and the
>   rest of the disk went to a massive /home partition.
>
> *Caveat*: I chose to use btrfs which – as I learned along the way – makes things a bit more complicated down the line. For your sanity's
>   sake I recommend using ext4. This guide assumes the use of btrfs and
>   will point out the caveats with this approach.
>
> **Fix Windows 10 boot**
>
> Unfortunately the Ubuntu Installer assumes that you want a dual
>   booting configuration alongside Windows. Therefore it adds itself
>   (actually, the bootloader it uses, GRUB2) to your computer's UEFI
>   configuration. This causes two problems. For starters, the external
>   HDD is not portable as you cannot boot with it on another computer.
>
> Secondly, if you remove this external HDD your Windows won't boot.
>   Bummer. We have to fix that.
>
> - Shut down your computer.
> - Disconnect the Ubuntu HDD
> - Boot from the Windows system repair disc USB drive (or a Windows installation or rescue CD-ROM/DVD-ROM).
> - Select *Repair your computer*.
> - Select the operating system and click *Next*.
> - Choose *Command Prompt*.
> - In the command prompt run
>
>   ```
>   diskpart
>   sel disk 0
>   list vol
>   ```
> - Verify that the EFI partition is using the FAT32 file system. It will have a volume ID, let's say 99. Now we need to assign a drive
>     letter to it. Back in the command prompt type:
>
>   ```
>   sel vol 99
>   assign letter=z:
>   exit
>   ```
> - Now we need to fix the boot record. Again in the command prompt type:
>
>   ```
>   z: 
>   cd EFI/Microsoft/Boot
>   bootrec /FixBoot
>   ```
> - Finally, we need to re-create the BCD store which tells the Microsoft boot loader where to find Windows so it can boot it. From
>     our trusted command prompt:
>
>   ```
>   ren BCD BCD.old
>   bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s z: All
>   ```
> - If this didn't work try:
>
>   ```
>   ren BCD BCD.old
>   bootrec /RebuildBcd
>   ```
>
> At this point exit the command prompt and shut down your computer.
>
> **Create an ESP on the Ubuntu HDD**
>
> A hard drive is not bootable with UEFI unless it has an ESP (EFI
>   System Partition). An ESP is simply a FAT32 partition with a special
>   flag that tells the EFI BIOS to look inside it for boot information.
>   We have to create one on your hard drive.
>
> - Plug in your external HDD and the Ubuntu Linux bootable USB stick.
> - Boot with the Ubuntu Linux bootable USB stick using the option to try Ubuntu before installing.
> - Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
> - Run `sudo fdisk -l` to get a list of partitions.
> - Identify from them the drive that has the Linux partitions, in my case `/dev/sdb`. I'll call it `/dev/sd<b>X</b>` from now on.
> - Also identify the partition that contains the root filesystem. I will call it /dev/sdXY from now on.
> - Launch GParted from the Terminal:
>
>   ```
>   sudo gparted /dev/sdX
>   ```
>
>   Why not just click on GParted on your desktop? Well, I kept receiving errors about the Ubuntu Linux bootable USB stick because it
>     was already in use. Of course it is, I am using it to run the computer
>     off it, duh!
> - Resize the first partition on disk to have another 200 Mb of free space after it.
> - Create a new partition on the free space, changing the file system to fat32.
> - Apply operations. You need to do that now for the next step to be possible.
> - Right click the new partition.
> - Click on Manage Flags.
> - Set the boot and esp flags. This is what makes the partition "special" to the EFI BIOS.
> - One more thing! Note down the the partition that contains the ESP filesystem. I will call it /dev/sd**XZ** from now on.
>
> **Make sure the Ubuntu installation on the external HDD can see the ESP**
>
> The new ESP on the external drive must be visible by the Ubuntu
>   installation in the HDD. Otherwise GRUB2, the Linux bootloader, won't
>   be able to update itself, making your system unbootable after the next
>   kernel update at the latest.
>
> - Launch GParted from the Terminal, as we saw above:
>
>   ```
>   sudo gparted /dev/sdX
>   ```
> - Double-click the partition with your Linux root (/) filesystem on the external HDD
> - Note down the UUID, e.g. `01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-4567890abcde`
> - Double-click the new FAT32 partition and note down the UUID, e.g. `0123-ABCD`
> - Close GParted
> - Open a Terminal
>
> The process is different depending on the format of your root
>   partition on the external hard disk.
>
> If you DID NOT use btrfs (e.g. you used ext4)
>
> ```
> sudo umount /media/ubuntu/01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-4567890abcde   
> sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
> ```
>
> If you DID use btrfs
>
> If you DID use btrfs, you made your life complicated. We need to mount
>   the btrfs subvolume containing the root partition instead of the
>   entire partition. Otherwise you'll never be able to install GRUB and
>   you'll probably lose an entire day, like me.
>
> ```
> btrfs subvolume list /media/ubuntu/01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-4567890abcde
> ```
>
> This will give you a line with a numeric ID. Let's say 123. Note it
>   down.
>
> ```
> umount /media/ubuntu/01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-4567890abcde  
> mount /dev/sdXY -o subvolid=123 /mnt
> ```
>
> The rest of the instructions are common, no matter if used btrfs, ext4
>   or something else
>
> ```
>     sudo nano /mnt/etc/fstab
> ```
>
> - There is a line with `/boot/efi` already in this file. Comment it by placing a `#` in front of it.
> - Add the following line:
>
>   ```
>   UUID=0123-ABCD /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
>   ```
>
> **Install GRUB2 on the external drive's EFI System Partition**
>
> Right now our external drive has an empty ESP. We need to put a
>   bootloader in it to make it actually, well, bootable.
>
> *First caveat*: all the instructions you find on-line assume you are using a dual boot system with Windows or macOS. When you have an
>   external drive it is critical that you use the `--removable` option in
>   the last step. This installs the EFI bootloader under the special
>   "fallback path" EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi in the ESP. Normally this not
>   supposed to be used for permanently installed Operating Systems. It's
>   the mechanism used by EFI BIOS to boot arbitrary external media.
>   Technically, that's exactly what our external hard drive is: arbitrary
>   external media!
>
> *Second caveat*: installing the bootloader is only possible from inside the Linux installation we want to boot. However, we need the
>   bootloader to boot that installation, leading to a Catch-22 issue. The
>   solution is to run the bootloader installation through a chroot jail.
>   The actual caveat that got me stumped for a day comes from the fact
>   that I am using btrfs (because it's so much better for SSDs!). btrfs
>   has subvolumes. If you mount the entire partition instead of a
>   subvolume the grub-install script can't figure out the mapping between
>   paths and devices, therefore failing to install itself on the ESP,
>   returning the cryptic error:
>
> ```
> /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
> ```
>
> The error is misleading! `/dev` is mounted if you follow my
>   instructions below. The actual problem, as I understand it, is that
>   there is a discrepancy between the mounted device and the path to the
>   chroot root. That's why I had you mount only the subvolume containing
>   the root filesystem in the steps above. If you were not paying
>   attention, you are not following the instructions step-by-step, you
>   rebooted before this step or just came here directly looking for a
>   solution to your problem about GRUB not installing look above for
>   instructions on mounting the correct btrfs subvolume.
>
> - We need to prepare the chroot environment. The ESP must be mounted in the correct place and we have to bind system mount point for some
>     special trees (most notably /dev). Moreover, we will copy the
>     resolv.conf file to let the chroot environment have network access
>     should it need it.
>
>   ```
>   mount /dev/sdXZ /mnt/boot/efi  
>   for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt/$i; done  
>   cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/  
>   modprobe efivars
>   ```
> - Finally we enter the chroot environment and install Grub in a way suitable for a removable device (see the first caveat above).
>
>   ```
>   sudo chroot /mnt  
>   grub-install -d /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi/ --removable /dev/sdX
>   ```
>
> Now your external HDD is bootable. Reboot your computer, select it
>   from the boot media selection of your UEFI BIOS and you're done!

Comment: Good tutorial :-) The next step is to make the USB drive bootable in both UEFI and BIOS mode ;-)