# Stuck on GRUB, won't load win 10 or Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I tried to make a live Ubuntu USB. By following these instructions. 
[Can I install Ubuntu to my 32 GB USB pen drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive)
And now my laptop won't load win 10 or Ubuntu. It's stuck on GRUB.

So I believe that the root file is on the USB and I can't get grub to detect the flash drive. When I do "ls" all I get is is "hd0"  with 5 gpt (0-4). On gpt1 I have Microsoft, Boot, and Ubuntu.

I'm at a loss for what to do.

Edit: on hd0,1 I have three files efi, boot, system volume information

In the efi file i have Microsoft, Boot, and Ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot) and [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/q/689258/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just your MBR or grub at fault (and you didn't accidentally wipe your os), try booting on a LiveCD and run boot-repair, that should fix grub and add existing operating systems it can find back to the menu.

With the Ubuntu LiveCD, open a terminal and run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

then start it with

```
boot-repair
```

There are advanced options available, but the automated ("Recommended repair") option works in most cases.

Comment: When I was playing with Ubuntu before this happened to boot off of USB I had to load windows,  open settings, select update and security, and then it would allow me to boot from USB or CD. It never gives me a chance to load from CD before that point. And when I use the "ls"  command it says error from cd0.     I'll try making a live CD though and get back to you on it.

Comment: Did as recommended and it no longer says error on CD but I can't seem to get it to boot. It now has cd0, cd0 apple1, cd0 apple2, cd0 msdos2. Only apple2 can be read and it doesnt have a root file. All the others return unknown filesystem.

Comment: Hm, that is very strange, when you were on the livecd, did your drives show up there? This might help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System