# Password for Live Session User in Ubuntu/Gnome 16.04

Tags: gnome, live-usb, password

I am new to Linux and I know that variations of this question have been asked before. However, none of the answers reflect what I see so I thought I'd try again from scratch,

I have installed live/persistent Ubuntu/Gnome 16.04 LTS to a USB stick using the Universal USB Installer at pendrivelinux.com

I can boot from the USB key and, using the "Try Ubuntu,,," option, get taken straight into a Gnome desktop without being asked for a password. If I log out of this session, I cannot log back in again because I don't know the password. I have searched this forum and find:

Some people have said quite categorically that the password is blank; wrong, this doesn't work.

Other people have said equally categorically that the password is "ubuntu"; wrong again, this doesn't work.

"Ubuntu" (another "definitive answer" in this forum) also doesn't work.

I have also tried, from other suggestions in this forum "utnubu", "reverse" and null. None of these works.

Help.

Please.

Comment: The default user profile has no password at all, not even an empty password. However, there should be no need to enter a password to access the user profile either. The described behaviour sound like a bug that you should [report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.com/). In the mean time, don't log out of the default user account of the live system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install Ubuntu to my 32 GB USB pen drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive)

Comment: I want to log out because I want to log in as another user that has a password to protect the data. I don't want this data available to the default user with no password protection.

Comment: *Running a live session:* It works for me in standard Ubuntu with the user ID 'ubuntu' and no password (just press the Enter key in the password box). Correspondingly it works in Lubuntu with the user ID 'lubuntu' and no password. I don't know about Ubuntu Gnome, but you can observe the user ID, when logged in and running a terminal window, and I would try with 'no password' there too. -- I guess you know the user ID and password of the other user that you created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a password as soon as you login. To do this, run the following command in a terminal:

```
passwd
```

Then, press <kbd>enter</kbd> if it asks for the current password because it should currently be blank.

Then, type a password when it asks you to and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Confirm the password by typing it in again when you are asked to do so and then press <kbd>enter</kbd> .

You should now be able to log out and then back in again using this password.

note: You may need to do this again the next time you boot up using the USB stick.

Comment: The live image username for Ubuntu Budgie is `ununtu-budgie`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu It *should* be but sometimes the default password doesn't work for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the actual answer. Username is `ubuntu-studio` and no password. Based on the above response with Lubuntu login for live session, that actually worked.